# meta data of an instance within AWS and provide a json formatted output

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, shell, amazon-ec2, aws-cli

I am AWS newbie and I need to write code that will query the meta data of an instance within aws and provide a json formatted output.
I have used the following command to get the output :
wget -q -O - http://169.254.169.254/latest/dynamic/instance-identity/document

The code allows for a particular data key to be retrieved individually. Please let me know how this can be achieved using any language or was cli

Answer (score 1):

You can take the response body of this request, parse with with json any library like Python's `json` package and use that. If you want to get more data than this url offers, try `http://169.254.169.254/latest/meta-data`.
This will give you more data to choose from.